# Multiple Custom UIPickerViews in the same UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Im trying to have two different pickerViews on the same viewController and let them represent different data. I have tried a different ways to do this, but both picker views showing same Data, but can't put it all together. Any help would be awesome!

here is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Eventtype: UITextField!


    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    var Eventstype = ["Birthday" , "Marriege" , "Get together", "Conference"]

    @IBOutlet weak var datepickertxt: UITextField!

    var datepicker = UIDatePicker()

    @IBOutlet weak var Duration: UITextField!
     let duration = UIPickerView()

    var Durations = ["6-8","1-5","7-9","10-12"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createDatePicker()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        duration.delegate = self
        duration.dataSource = self
        Eventtype.inputView = pickerView
        Duration.inputView = duration
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    ////For Event Picker view

     func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1


    }

     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
            //pickerView1
            return Eventstype.count
        } else if (duration.tag == 1){
            //pickerView2
            return Durations.count
        }
        return 1
        //return DurationTxt.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {

            return Eventstype[row]
        } else if (duration.tag == 1){

           return Durations[row]
        }

        return ""
    }
        //return DurationTxt[row]


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
            Eventtype.text = Eventstype[row]
            self.view.endEditing(false)
        }else if (duration.tag == 1){
            Duration.text = Durations[row]
            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are checking the tags, but you did not assign values for both picker views tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tags for pickerview in viewDidLoad as shown below,

```
pickerView.tag = 0
duration.tag = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Eventtype: UITextField!


    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    var Eventstype = ["Birthday" , "Marriege" , "Get together", "Conference"]

    @IBOutlet weak var datepickertxt: UITextField!

    var datepicker = UIDatePicker()

    @IBOutlet weak var Duration: UITextField!
     let duration = UIPickerView()

    var Durations = ["6-8","1-5","7-9","10-12"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createDatePicker()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        duration.delegate = self
        duration.dataSource = self
        Eventtype.inputView = pickerView
        Duration.inputView = duration
        pickerView.tag = 0
        duration.tag = 1
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    ////For Event Picker view

     func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1


    }

     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
            //pickerView1
            return Eventstype.count
        } else if (duration.tag == 1){
            //pickerView2
            return Durations.count
        }
        return 1
        //return DurationTxt.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {

            return Eventstype[row]
        } else if (duration.tag == 1){

           return Durations[row]
        }

        return ""
    }
        //return DurationTxt[row]


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
            Eventtype.text = Eventstype[row]
            self.view.endEditing(false)
        }else if (duration.tag == 1){
            Duration.text = Durations[row]
            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

    }
```

This is done by tag or else yo can check in delegate like

```
if pickerView == duration
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txtDuration: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtEventType: UITextField!

    var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    var arrEventType : [String] = []
    var arrDuration : [String] = []

    var currentTextField : UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrEventType = ["Birthday" , "Marriage" , "Get together", "Conference"]
        arrDuration  = ["6-8","1-5","7-9","10-12"]
    }
}

extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if currentTextField == txtEventType {
            return arrEventType.count
        } else if currentTextField == txtDuration {
            return arrDuration.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if currentTextField == txtEventType {
            return arrEventType[row]
        } else if currentTextField == txtDuration {
            return arrDuration[row]
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if currentTextField == txtEventType {
            txtEventType.text = arrEventType[row]
        } else if currentTextField == txtDuration {
            txtDuration.text = arrDuration[row]
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.pickerView.delegate   = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        currentTextField = textField
        if currentTextField == txtEventType {
            currentTextField?.inputView = pickerView
        } else if currentTextField == txtDuration {
            currentTextField?.inputView  = pickerView
        }

    }
}
```

Above lines of code may solve your issue with just one UIPickerView and without tags